# OpenLayers fitting before add features

Tags: javascript, openlayers

**Problem:** Open layers is fitting to map and only after is adding features (visually), how can i avoid this?

im doing this

*step 1 - creating the features*

```
var feature = new ol.Feature({...});
```

*step 2 - adding them to source*

```
source.addFeature(feature);
```

*step 3 - and fitting like this*

```
view.fit(source.getExtent(), { duration: 1000 });
```

but visually is showed step 3 -> step 1 -> step 2

i want to do step 1 -> step 2 -> step 3 (by code order)

Comment: added a timeout on `.fit` for now but i liked to know a better way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and fit the view on [`addfeature`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.Event.html#event:addfeature)

```
source.on('addfeature', function() {
    view.fit(source.getExtent());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to create the layer without a source, and set the source of the layer after `view.fit`:

```
const layer = new ol.layer.Vector();
const source = new ol.source.Vector();
source.addFeature(feature);
view.fit(source.getExtent());
layer.setSource(source);
```

Comment: but that will `fit` first, what i need is to `fit` after